# Restfull point in polygon in SQL Azure

Tags: json, rest, azure, geospatial

I want to create a restfull WCF service in Azure to store polygons drawn in Bing maps. Each polygon has also a descriptive text. Response format must be JSON.

The most important feature must be to retrieve the list of polygons (with text) for a given point (lat long) (so I must have a point in polygon routine).

I am not a geo expert, but I was recommended to use the geo spatial part of SQL Azure. How can this be done ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a suggestion.
 - First try implementing your polygon detection in standard SQL Server.
 - then port your SQL Server solution to an Azure equivalent.
 - and finally expose a WCF interface to your functionality.

If you break it down like this you may find it easier to ask more specific questions that are more likely to get answered.

Comment: Yeah, i did already. Created a local DB and tested a SP for point in polygon; that works. Only I cannot read the polygon column from a  SQLDataReader....

Comment: @Patrick  Ok, so show the code that is not working and we will try and help.

Comment: Well.. I made some progress here. The problem now is that I cannot get any rows from the SP. This the code:  SqlParameter sqlParameter = sqlCommand.CreateParameter();
                    sqlParameter.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Float;
                    sqlParameter.ParameterName = "@latitude";
                    sqlParameter.Value = latitude;
                    sqlCommand.Parameters.Add(sqlParameter);

                    sqlParameter = sqlCommand.CreateParameter();
                    sqlParameter.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Float;
                    sqlParameter.ParameterName = "@longitude";

Comment: Argghh... the SqlDBType.Float was the issue here: I removed this row and now I get rows back. The only issue now is: I have a SqlGeometry type, and I want to have all the LatLong coordinates as one string...